# Find if the value of key is found in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a list of Keys, 0000-9999.

These keys are also stored in the comment in another field:

e.g:

```
key         comment

12345       'foobar 45356'

45356       'foobar 148512'
```

What I'm attempting to achieve is this:
`Select * from Table where comment like (select key from Table)`

**What I've tried:**

I've also attempted using the CONTAINS keyword: e.g. `Where comment contains (select....)`, however I can't put in wild cards....

**Question:**

How do I achieve what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
     CommentTable.comment
    ,KeyTable.key
from CommentTable
join KeyTable
    on CommentTable.comment like ('%' + KeyTable.key + '%')
```

If the key is not a varchar, replace the `on` with the following

```
    on CommentTable.comment like ('%' + cast(KeyTable.key as varchar(max)) + '%')
```

Comment: Also Note that Key needs to be varchar, otherwise the engine will try and sum instead of concatenate them, if it's an int then you can use `Cast(KeyTable.key as varchar[50])`

Comment: Good point, the example I threw together was a string, I'll add that to the answer. Thanks!